# Accessing a property of a non-static class without assigning it to a variable

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

I am writing a custom automation framework using Selenium, C# and Page Object Pattern.
I am trying to extract some values from the pages without stopping the statement.

Basically I want to turn this:

```
    var page = Login()
        .OpenPage();

    page.Remember(page.Title);
    page.MoreActions()
        .MoreNavigation();
```

into this:

```
    var page = Login()
        .OpenPage()
        .Remember(???.Title)
        .MoreActions()
        .MoreNavigation();
```

Not sure if it is possible and how I could access the class at that point.

Notes:

- All the methods return pages
- There is a base `Page` class and a lot of `PageName : Page<PageName>` classes representing the actual classes that I use in the tests
- I want to implement the Remember method in the `Page` class so that I can use it everywhere.
- Classes have Properties that I want to use to remember the values

```
LoginPage : NavPage<LoginPage>
{
    public override string Title => "Hardcoded Title";
    public string OtherProperty => pageContent.GetSomeValue();
...
}
```

- I have a dictionary of parameters in the tests. I want to remember the value in one of the parameters.

Solutions that I cannot use:

- Making the classes static and using the class name is not an option as we have our page structure based on inheritance and overloading methods.
- Creating RememberTitle methods on all the pages is not an option because I want to remember the value into a Dictionary of parameters and such a parameter cannot be passed by reference.

Update:
As per comments I tried implementing a lamda expression:

```
        public static NavPage<T> Remember(this NavPage<T> page, Func<NavPage<T>, string> getTitle)
        {
            var title = getTitle(page);                      
            //use Title
            return page;
        }
```

```
  .Remember(p => p.Title);
```

The new error is `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter getTitle`

Comment: It is not possible if these methods do not return the object you are after., in order for this to be possible the library and each of these methods need to have some sort of fluent API support eg. by returning the object type which has the next method you are trying to chain available.

Check whether the `.Remember()` method has an overload that allows you to pass in a lamda such as `.Remember(r => r.Page)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but I assume you can write an extension method for page type called smth like `RememberTitle`, call the `Remember` method inside & return the page back. Same for other methods.

Comment: Maybe this needs a little clarification: This is a custom framework using Page object Model. All the methods return objects, including Remember().
@DavidOganov The problems with creating RememberTItle like methods for all the things we want to remember are 
1) a LOT of extra methods in the Page classes
2) the fact that I want to remember the value into a custom parameter dictionary that is out of scope on the pages.
@Stefanos lamda  seems to be the way to go; I am trying to do something like that but I am not sure what `r` should be

Comment: @IoanaNicu it doesn't matter whether that is a custom framework or written by you. What I'm proposing to do is to have a method like this: `public static Page Remember(this Page page, Func<Page, string> getTitle)
        {
            var title = getProperty(page);
            // Use the title
            return page;
        }` I'll post this as an answer for better formating & readability

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to achieve your desired result.
Let's say the *page* that you mentioned is of type `Page` & the *Title* that you've mentioned is of type `string`. Then you can have the following extension method:

```
public static Page Remember(this Page page, Func<Page, string> getTitle)         
{             
    var title = getTitle(page);             
    // Use the title
    page.Remember(page.title);

    // Return page object for further chaining
    return page;         
}
```

Then you can use this extension method the following way:

```
 var page = Login()
    .OpenPage()
    .Remember(p => p.Title)
    .MoreActions()
    .MoreNavigation();
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, but I can't get it to work. I added more details about the internals of the pages. Maybe there is some critical information there that I overlooked when trying to simplify the code.